# Next in sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Good day.

A friend of mine was presented this problem of "next in secuence" as an idle exercise by her math professor, and I'm curious what could be the answer for it. It is making no sense to me, but she tells me that it was faithfully copied from the blackboard.

The problem is as follows:

```
1
11
21
1211
111221
312211
```

and we're looking for the next line in the secuence. What I don't know is if it should be treated as a logical problem or an aritmethical one. The math class is basic (pre-algebra, even) but I don't know if this problem has any relation to the material they're studying on class.

If anyone can tell me what is the answer, I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: It's called the "Look and Say sequence". Each term is a description of the previous one (e.g., "two ones", "one two, one one", etc.). See http://oeis.org/A005150

Comment: Hence the next element is $13112221$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll pass along the answer, thank you. I couldn't decypher it, and I think my friend couldn't either. thanks

Comment: Erm... how can I mark the question as answered? XP

Comment: I think if you give your own answer, you can accept that if no other answers exist.